# Check wether clicking a link loads ajax content and is logged in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Im trying to see if a page generates an ajax content load and google analytics click tracking for a splash page.

Eg. i would like to know if clicking 'entre' on their splashpage will mean that the visit will not be tracked as a bounce in google analyitcs.

Any idea how i can check this through my browsers debugging tools ?

The site in question with the splash page im trying to analyse is [THIS SITE](http://bit.ly/2iBfzzL)

Answer (score 1):

Use real time analytics to see what gets loaded.

Open Google Analytics and go to the real time reports.  Then click on the link and see immediately whether or not in registers.

I've found that browser debugging tools are not as good.   It is easy to miss something and it is nowhere near as convenient as the real time reporting.